# Fontconfig error: line 126: junk after document element

Tags: fonts

when i give this **command gedit test13.c**, I'm getting this kind of error but its opening the file. if i try this with another file name like this **command gedit test12.c** there was no error.

ubuntu@ubuntu-OptiPlex-360:~/Naresh/desktop$ gedit test13.c
Fontconfig warning: line 103: Having multiple values in  isn't supported and may not work as expected
Fontconfig error: line 126: junk after document element
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

test13.c contains:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("0x7A, 0");
    //printf("\xE6\x91\x83\n");
}
```

Comment: What does the file `test13.c` look like?

Comment: look like normal C file only

Comment: I think you need to show us the file; without it it's unlikely that somebody will be able to comment further.

Comment: test13.c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         #include <stdio.h>

void main()
{

 printf("0x7A, 0"); 
  //printf("\xE6\x91\x83\n"); 

}                                                                                                                                                                   this is the code i have test13.c file

Comment: Ok, I can't reproduce the problem on my Ubuntu 16.10. Which version are you on, and which version of gedit?

Comment: Ubuntu  16.04.2 and gedit version is 3.18.3

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think this is related to some font which is used when rendering that file on your machine, i.e. there is some font configuration file for that font with a bad syntax. There have been several bug reports about this issue in the past; [this](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1034928) is one example. If you have installed fonts manually, it could be a possible explanation.

In any case: It's just a warning, and nothing to worry about.